# Como mostrar un dialogo con check marcados predefinidos?

Tags: java, android-studio, alertdialog

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente Dialog con Lista De Múltiple Selección De Checkboxes, Como puedo hacer para que al momento de llamar al Dialogo, me muestre con check algunos items? por ejemplo, si quiero que me cargue con check el item 5 y el item 9, como puedo hacer?

```
public AlertDialog listDialogHimnos() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final String[] listitems = ListaHimnos.arreglo.tokens;
    builder.setTitle("Himnos 1 - 371")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(listitems, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        //Si hay check
                    } else {
                        //Si se quita el check
                    }
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto mi pregunta!
Antes que nada he declarado mi lista del dialog como variable global, a la vez, he declarado otra variable de tipo boleana del tamaño de mi lista en la que se guardara una lista del estado de los items con check

```
final String[] listitems = ListaHimnos.arreglo.tokens;
final boolean bl[] = new boolean[listitems.length];
```

El dialogo me queda de la siguiente manera:

```
public AlertDialog listDialogHimnos() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Himnos 1 - 371")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(listitems, bl, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        //Si hay check
                        bl[which] =true;//Guardo el estado en esta posicion
                    } else {
                        //Si se quita el check
                        bl[which] = false;//Elimino el estado de esta posicion
                    }
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Como pueden ver en

```
.setMultiChoiceItems(listitems, bl,.........
```

*listitems* es la lista que me muestra en el dialogo
*bl* es la variable boleana con los estados de los items

Answer (score 0):

Con `setChecked` de esta forma:

```
tuCheckBox5.setChecked(true);
tuCheckBox9.setChecked(true);
```